# How to set the user_AuthenticatedId for the requests in Application Insight from Azure Function?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I'm using Azure Functions to serve mobile clients and between them, there is an Azure API Management. I also use Application Insights to monitor requests coming to the backend. The default logging creates requests in AppInsights but some field (for example `user_AuthenticatedId`) is empty which could be useful for me. Also on the Users page in AppInsights I can only see one user where the id is "<undefined>"

[Requests in Application Insight look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbYPA.png)

In the Azure Function, I get an access token that contains the id of the user and I want to set this as the `user_AuthenticatedId`. I tried to configure a `TelemetryClient` and start a new `Operation` where I set the `operation.Telemetry.Context.User.AuthenticatedUserId = _userID;` but with this, the request was duplicated on AppInsights.

Is it possible from the code of the Azure Function to set the properties of the request telemetry which is created by default?

My Function methods look like this:

```cs
[FunctionName("TestFunction")]
public async Task<IActionResult> RunAsync(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, HttpMethod.Get)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    try
    {
        //do some stuff
        return new OkObjectResult(<result>);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //handle exception
        return new ObjectResult(<result>);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**To see in the logs terminal, use below code snippet :**

```
log.LogInformation(tc.Context.User.AuthenticatedUserId);
```

**To see it in application insights, use  `TrackTrace`  or  `TrackEvent`:**

```
tc.TrackEvent("---------track-event" + tc.Context.User.AuthenticatedUserId);
tc.TrackTrace("---------track-trace" + tc.Context.User.AuthenticatedUserId);
```

**Here `tc` is Telemetry Client.
For example, here is the sample code I have :**

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using System.Security.Claims;
using ikvm.runtime;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace SuryaFunctionApp3
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly TelemetryClient tc;

        public Function1(TelemetryConfiguration config)
        {
            this.tc = new TelemetryClient(config);
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log, ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
        {

            tc.Context.User.AuthenticatedUserId = "---userid---";

            log.LogInformation(tc.Context.User.AuthenticatedUserId);
            tc.TrackEvent("---------track-event" + tc.Context.User.AuthenticatedUserId);
            tc.TrackTrace("---------track-trace" + tc.Context.User.AuthenticatedUserId);

            string responseMessage = "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully";

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }

        public class MyStartup : IWebJobsStartup
        {
            public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
            {
                var configDescriptor = builder.Services.SingleOrDefault(tc => tc.ServiceType == typeof(TelemetryConfiguration));
                if (configDescriptor?.ImplementationFactory != null)
                {
                    var implFactory = configDescriptor.ImplementationFactory;
                    builder.Services.Remove(configDescriptor);
                    builder.Services.AddSingleton(provider =>
                    {
                        if (implFactory.Invoke(provider) is TelemetryConfiguration config)
                        {
                            var newConfig = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
                            newConfig.ApplicationIdProvider = config.ApplicationIdProvider;
                            newConfig.InstrumentationKey = config.InstrumentationKey;

                            return newConfig;
                        }
                        return null;
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to see the user_id in the Requests which created automatically in app insights. Don't want to introduce new events